# Can you identify this Art Nouveau font in a metal plate?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have seen this before but I cannot find it via Google Images, nor via other font identifiers. I know I used it before, back when my workstation was Windows. I have already traced the other object and I'm just lacking this type.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic Art Nouveau Style font [Arnold Boecklin](https://www.wfonts.com/font/arnold-boecklin) via wfonts.com

[image]